# How to search a text using Enter key in blue prism

Tags: blueprism

I have a search box where I can enter the search text however there is no search button next to it. So we use to press enter button after enter the search text in text box.

Please advise how to handle this in blue prism. I have tried using Global Send Keys however the focus moved out of the search box hence nothing happening

If the mouse focus is inside the text box then you can see a 'X' mark inside it

[image]

If I use the global sendkeys then the mouse focus is outside the text box as below

[image]

Comment: Can you click the magnifying glass icon to trigger the search function?

Comment: No esqew.. thats the problem

Comment: Could you get a screenshot of the above while in html mode (Alt key cycle) so we can see what can be selected? you should be able to spy that magnifying glass into an model element and then use a mouse click centre as usual. Also, have you tried using Global Send Keys "{ENTER}" or some other syntax?

Comment: Also, please go to Application Modeller and highlight the element you are using for the Sendkey from the tree on the left, then please take a screenshot of that too.

Answer (score 1):

To go about this issue, I would first try to set the focus on the field, by sending a Global Mouse Click Center (not just focus) to the Textbox.

Next, send the "{ENTER}" or "~" key to the Textbox, using **Send Global Keys**.

I would assume that if that doesn't work, you have spied the container of the Textbox, not the Textbox itself somehow.

Alternatively, as a last resort you can also choose to send a Javascript command to the webpage, in order to trigger the form submission. This can be achieved by using the Navigate stage on the Application Model's top element (highest in hierarchy).

Good luck!